# In my Windows Store App propagate event from my UserControl to container Page

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I am developing an App in Windows 8.1 for the Store Windows and using MVVM with Unity as a dependency injector, my scenario is as follows.

I have a `UserControl` that contains a `ListView`, when I click on an of my Items (`behaviors:ItemClickCommandBehavior. ItemClickCommand = "{Binding ClickListCommand}")`, I want to capture this event in my ViewModel from my page this `UserControl` container, how I do?

Thank you

Comment: You forgot the most important information: Why do you want to propagate this event to the page. It may be important for the readers to decide if you are on a completely wrong track (i.e. about to violate MVVM pattern) or if a different solution is more appropriate

Comment: Why do you think that I am not correctly using the MVVM pattern??

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say. We'd need to know **why** the page does need to know about a change in your UserControl. If in reality, only the Page's ViewModel needs to know it, you need to handle it differently that if you really want the **Page** know it. If it's going to trigger some kind of animation (View logic) for example, it'd be View related code. If it's about to trigger some other kind of logic, it  may be ViewModel (Presentation Logic) related

Comment: I want to use a UserControl because I saw need on more than one screen. On the other hand the UserControl has a ListView that when pulse in an item is upgraded, a part of the screen, in particular a graphic

Comment: Expose a RoutedEvent on the surface of your UserControl for this event.  Wire it appropriately inside the codebehind of your control. Bind to it appropriately outside.  Done.